# Как перечислять cte?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Есть запрос:

```
with t(id1,dept_name1) as
(
    Код иерархии.......
)
select Distinct t.dept_name1 as Name
From t
UNION ALL
Select 'Все' as Name
```

Но здесь строка `Все` стоит вторым.
Хочу добавить строку `Все` и строка была первым. Попробовал так:

```
With rs as
 (Select 'Все' as Name)
 select  Name
 from rs
 UNION ALL
 t AS (id1,dept_name1) as
    (
        Код иерархии.......
    )
    select Distinct t.dept_name1 as Name
    From t
```

Как добавить строку и чтобы строка `Все` была первым?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Может быть так имелось в виду?

```
;with t(id1,dept_name1) as
(
    Код иерархии.......
)
Select 'Все' as Name
UNION ALL
select Distinct t.dept_name1 as Name
From t
```

Answer (score 2):

Добавьте сортировку. Используйте [CASE](http://www.sql-tutorial.ru/ru/book_case_order_by_clause.html).

Answer (score 1):

Если нужно именно несколько CTE - перечисляйте их через запятую:

```
;With rs as
 (Select 'Все' as Name),
 t (id1,dept_name1) as
    (
        Код иерархии.......
    )
 select  Name
 from rs
 UNION ALL
 select Distinct t.dept_name1 as Name
 From t
```

Но в данном случае CTE на "все" не нужен, хватит `Union`.

Comment: Привет, увидел у вас на личной странице Новосибирск. Приходите на встречу сообщества 12го декабря )

Comment: [Встреча сообщества Stack Overflow на русском в Москве и Новосибирске](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1838)